# CSS - Wrapping precedence

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 3 columns

```
**********************************************************
*  Name        *     Description               * Actions *
**********************************************************
*  John        * Lorem ipsum bla bla etc eetc  *   B1    *
*              *                               *   B2    *
**********************************************************
```

What happens is that the last column wraps its content first, then the description column. I would like the Description column to wrap first instead.
I tried adding white-space: nowrap but then the Actions column *never* wraps.

How does the browser decide which column to wrap?

I want the column 3 to be the last to wrap. So until the Description column is fully wrapped it should show the buttons on a single line. When there is no more space the column can wrap.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Entity</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer</td>
      <td>9004</td>
      <td>null, asdjkajk, kkkjk, kjkk, kkk, 898989</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn c-btn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn c-btn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS code with us. Or even better reproduce the problem in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: What are you using to do this? Are these floats? Are you using a css framework? If you could post a fiddle or something it would be easier to answer your question. It's a bit too open ended without knowing how you are implementing these columns.

Comment: try to increase width of last column

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant detail in the JSFiddle you've posted, including non-standard attributes and embedded images. Try to come up with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so you can test out different solutions without all the extra styling making it hard to understand.

Comment: You say the third column shouldn't wrap first, but you want it not to never wrap. When should it wrap, then?

Comment: Sorry @IMSoP, that's the code generated by GWT. I cleaned it up.

Comment: I want the 3 column to be the last to wrap. So until the Description column is fully wrapped it should show the buttons on a single line. When there is no more space the column can wrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns wrap their text in descending order in a table.
So you only need to fix the last column's width.

If you want it to wrap again in small screens, just add a media query (see CSS) to reset it's width to auto and give the columng it's priority to wrap.

```css
table{
  width:300px;
}

td{
  border:1px solid black;
}

table>tr>td:last-child{
  width:40px;
}

@media (max-width: 200px) {
  table>tr>td:last-child{
    width:auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td class="cc">Description</td>
    <td>Actions</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td class="cc">Lorem ipsum bla bla black test long text</td>
    <td>BA AB</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll use media query to set the 3rd column's "white-space: nowrap" for big screens and "white-space: normal" for small screens

Answer (score 3):

Give the first and last column a width. The center layout will then take all the remaining layout and wrap its contents if needed.

Comment: I need the last column to shrink if the screen become too small, but **after** the second column has wrapped

Comment: then just add the width to the last column and let the table handle the rest of the re-sizing, or do you ultimately need the last column to also decrease? If you are using a responsive framework, you should also have some classes you can use to help with the sizing. I don't think you have much control after that.

Answer (score 3):

See the [automatic table layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout) section in the spec:

> Column widths are determined as follows:
>
> 1. Calculate the minimum content width (MCW) of each cell: the formatted content may span any number of lines but may not overflow
>      the cell box. If the specified ['width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) (W) of the cell is greater
>      than MCW, W is the minimum cell width. A value of 'auto' means that
>      MCW is the minimum cell width.
> 2. Also, calculate the "maximum" cell width of each cell: formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line
>      breaks occur.
> 3. For each column, determine a maximum and minimum column width from the cells that span only that column. The minimum is that required by
>      the cell with the largest minimum cell width (or the column
>      ['width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width), whichever is larger). The maximum is that required by
>      the cell with the largest maximum cell width (or the column
>      ['width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width), whichever is larger).
> 4. For each cell that spans more than one column, increase the minimum widths of the columns it spans so that together, they are at least as
>      wide as the cell. Do the same for the maximum widths. If possible,
>      widen all spanned columns by approximately the same amount.
> 5. For each column group element with a 'width' other than 'auto', increase the minimum widths of the columns it spans, so that together
>      they are at least as wide as the column group's 'width'.
>
> This gives a maximum and minimum width for each column.
>
> The caption width minimum (CAPMIN) is determined by calculating for
>   each caption the minimum caption outer width as the MCW of a
>   hypothetical table cell that contains the caption formatted as
>   "display: block". The greatest of the minimum caption outer widths is
>   CAPMIN.
>
> Column and caption widths influence the final table width as follows:
>
> 1. If the 'table' or 'inline-table' element's ['width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) property has a computed value (W) other than 'auto', the used width is the
>      greater of W, CAPMIN, and the minimum width required by all the
>      columns plus cell spacing or borders (MIN). If the used width is
>      greater than MIN, the extra width should be distributed over the
>      columns.
> 2. If the 'table' or 'inline-table' element has 'width: auto', the used width is the greater of the table's containing block width,
>      CAPMIN, and MIN. However, if either CAPMIN or the maximum width
>      required by the columns plus cell spacing or borders (MAX) is less
>      than that of the containing block, use max(MAX, CAPMIN).

Note it says

> If the used width is greater than MIN, the extra width should be
>   distributed over the columns.

However, it doesn't specify how it should be distributed.

Moreover, the algorithm is non-normative:

> This algorithm reflects the behavior of several popular HTML user
>   agents at the writing of this specification. UAs are not required to
>   implement this algorithm.

Therefore, the behavior is **implementation-dependent**.